# Objects don't seem to get saved into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework code-first and the following two models:

```
public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public enum Answers
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }
    public string AnswerB { get; set; }
    public string AnswerC { get; set; }
    public string AnswerD { get; set; }
    public Answers Correct { get; set; }
}
```

The two models above show a relationship between `Exam` and `Question`; `Exam` has multiple `Question`s. To my understanding this relationship gets correctly created by Entity Frameworks' code-first.

However, when I try to read the questions inside an `Exam` object (after supposedly being added to the database), the `Exam` object shows `Null` for the `Questions` collection. Why does this happen? The object gets correctly created using the following create method. I have debugged through its process and the `Exam` object gets its questions assigned correctly.

```
public ActionResult Create(ExamVM examVM)
{
    // Return if no questions were selected.
    if (examVM.Questions == null)
        return View(examVM);

    // Create database-exam object.
    QuestionaireDbContext db = new QuestionaireDbContext();
    Exam exam = new Exam();
    exam.Questions = new List<Question>();

    // Fill exam with selected questions.
    foreach (QuestionVM questionVM in examVM.Questions.Where(q => q.IsSelected))
        exam.Questions.Add(db.Questions.Find(questionVM.ID));

    exam.Name = examVM.Name;
    exam.CreationDate = DateTime.Today;

    // Validate exam.
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Exams.Add(exam);
        db.SaveChanges();
        // Return to index if changes were applied.
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Return if exam isn't valid.
    return View(examVM);
}
```

Note that in the above method I use a "helper" model (`ExamVM`) to assign the questions to the exam.

To repeat the question: why does my `Exam` object return `Null` for its `Questions` collection when querying from the database, while it gets correctly created and supposedly also correctly added to the database?

I read the exam using the following method:

```
public ActionResult TakeExam(int id)
{
     QuestionaireDbContext db = new QuestionaireDbContext();
     Exam exam = db.Exams.Find(id);
     return View("TakeExam", exam);
}
```

The exam holds the correct Name etc, but the collection shows to be null.

This is the `DbContext`, for reference:

```
public class QuestionaireDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do not forget to wrap your QuestionaireDbContext with using block http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Comment: Make collection property `virtual`. The lazy loading works only if properties are virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to enable lazy loading by making the Questions property virtual, or explicitly load the collection using

```
dbContext.Exams.Include(e => e.Questions)
```

Comment: I would have to use this line when querying on the exams? And otherwise alter my models with a virtual keyword for the collection? Note that your line doesn't seem to compile. Signature doesn't allow lambda..

Comment: You claim the issue occurs when queuing your exams, so yes. It would help if you'd verify the items are saved to the database and show the relevant code for reading the exams.

Comment: Regarding your edit: yes, make the Exam.Questions property virtual to use lazy loading or explicitly use dB.Exams.Include(e => e.Questions).Find().

Comment: Search the web for the compile error and you'll see you need to add 'using System.Data.Entity'. Or use the string "Questions".

Comment: Adding the using did solve the lambda issue, it still shows to be `null`, sadly. I will just try the lazy loading and update the database.